# React Router Dom redirects incorrectly upon building

Tags: reactjs, build, react-router-dom, react-scripts

Goal:  Reach http://localhost:3000/test.html?test=5

Problem:  When run in development mode and prior to building, I can reach http://localhost:3000/test.html?test=5 just fine.  However, after running 'react-scripts build', when navigating to http://localhost:3000/test.html?test=5, the page will redirect to http://localhost:3000/test with a status code 301 Moved Permanently.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Test from "./Test";

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Route path="*" component={Test} />
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Test.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>{this.props.location.pathname+this.props.location.search}</h1>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

I believe it has something to do with the URL containing '.html?'.  When I try to navigate to 'http://localhost:3000/test.html/test=5', it works just fine, but as soon as you try 'http://localhost:3000/test.html?test=5', it will redirect to 'http://localhost:3000/test'

I created a demo of the problem if anyone wants to test it.
[Demo](https://github.com/CongoCash/react-router-testing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why don't work react-router-dom after build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58182932/why-dont-work-react-router-dom-after-build)

Comment: go to this link you will find answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/58182932/8138584