# why don't work react-router-dom after build?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

links doesn't work after being build but it works in localhost:3000

I use react-router-dom component

build project with :

```
npm run build
```

app.js:

```
    return (  
      <div>
        <Router >
          <Header/>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
              <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
              <Route path="/join" component={Join}/>
              <Route path="/advertisement" component={Advertisement}/>
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
              <Route path="/details" component={Details}/>

        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and links in other components:

```
<ul>
    <li><Link to='/'>home</Link></li>
    <li><Link to='/about'>about us</Link></li>
    <li><Link to='/join'>join</Link></li>
    <li><Link to='/advertisement'>ads</Link></li>
    <li><Link to='/contact'>contact us</Link></li>
</ul>
```

package.json

```
"homepage": ".",
```

Comment: please add more code of route file

Comment: have you tried it or directly?

Comment: Does it work if you manually update the URL from browser? (if you use Browser router). If not, the problem is in the route itself. Check it out. If it did work, check the URL formed on the link and compare against the URL step

Comment: Post your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a very `specific reason` behind this scenario.

***1st solution :*** react is a single page application so when you have build the application , server know only about index.html so for  any other `url` you will have to `configure` server for `fallback mechanism to index.html` and after react app will take care of url handling.

***2nd solution***: if you use `hash router` than this issue will not occur.
the reason behind using hash router is [know more about hashrouter and it's use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51976069/8138584)

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

add switch from this library

```
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter >
       <Switch>
      <Header/>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
          <Route exact path="/join" component={Join}/>
          <Route exact path="/advertisement" component= 
           {Advertisement}/>
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
          <Route exact path="/details" component={Details}/>
     </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
```

try adding this way ,switch is required to wrap the Route component,hope this will help you

Comment: Switch is not required.